# How to get the body of post request in Scalatra?

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have a scalatra servlet:

```
post("/asdf") {
  ???
}
```

And my clients send xml in post body, so I need to extract raw text from request. How do I do it in scalatra?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
request.body
```

gives you access to the request body. So if it is XML and you want it as a NodeSeq, do:

```
XML.loadString(request.body)
```

Comment: Make sure that Content-Type is not 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (see Ross' answer on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatra-user/lApjIJXiNqg)

Answer (score 5):

+1, good question

You have access to Servlet Request via "request" keyword within a Scalatra route, so getInputStream and getContentLength provide access if the post body itself is the xml string; i.e. client is *not* passing xml stored in named field as part of a form post. If the latter, then the below should do the trick:

```
post("/foo" && request.getHeader("Accept-Encoding") contains "application/xml") {
  val xml = XML.fromString(params("xml-param-field-name"))
}
```

If you want to use above parse from string, see Anti-XML Integration in the [Scalatra Book](http://www.scalatra.org/2.1/book/)

Comment: am new to scala and doing this ^^ am getting compilation error on &&/contains.

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni not sure, it's been 5 years since I used Scalatra ;-) Maybe try their [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/scalatra/scalatra)